# How to configure the TTL for the ZF2 file based config and module map cache?

Tags: performance, caching, zend-framework2, config, ttl

In Zend Framework 2 it's possible to bundle all the configs as a merged array in on file. The same can be done for the module class map. It increases the performance a bit and is easy to set up (see also the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/config.advanced.html)):

**`/config/application.config.php`**

```
return array(
    ...
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        ...
        'config_cache_enabled' => true,
        'config_cache_key' => 'app_config',
        'module_map_cache_enabled' => true,
        'module_map_cache_key' => 'module_map',
        'cache_dir' => './data/cache',
    ),
);
```

The cache is file based (at least I didn't find a way to use a memory based cache like `memcached`).

**Is it possible / How to to define a time to live to the config cache in Zend Framework 2?**

Comment: I don't think it's possible. All I can think os is to create a script, which caches all dirs only in production (there is an example in the docs). Another way is probably to use `Zend\Cache\StorageFactory` and create your own cache.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! To the "another way" with using `Zend\Cache\StorageFactory`: You mean to wrap the cache file with a `Zend\Cache\Storage` object? Bot how to "explain" to the application, that it has to use this cache object and not the file. Could you please post an example?

Comment: Well, when you create the cached file with the abov code, you can than pass it in the cache\storage class with `addItem(), hasItem()` methods. However this is only a theory and I'm not sure if it's going to work. Will try to create an example today.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the cache is file based. For the sole reason, this is the configuration used before bootstrapping the app. Thus, loading Zend\Cache with all bits isn't an ideal case (as you preferable want to use a service manager config, after the service manager is configured, but you're still prior to bootstrapping).

All configs in ZF2 are files, so the easiest way is actually merge all files together and write them into a single file.

Next, TTL for this cache doesn't really make sense. You only have cache invalidation when you change your (file based!) module configuration. The only reason you change your config files is during deploys. After all, on dev and testing environments you don't cache configs and on production you only work with proper deployments (you are, right? ;) ).

The proper solution is therefore not to look at TTL but rather solve the cache invalidation during deployment. If you overwrite your app with new files, remove the cache. If you deploy a new version of you app in a new folder (capistrano alike) you don't have this problem at all.